# accessibility of a new variable (scope of "new")

Tags: c++, scope

It has to be a question that has already been asked, but I can't find any answer anywhere...

My problem is simple : I read that when a variable is created using the keyword `new`, its scope is not limited by the surrounding `{..}`.
So why does this code not compile ?

```
{
std::string * s = new std::string("foo");
}

std::cout << "print : " << (*s) << std::endl;
```

Visual Sudio tells me : "identifier "s" is undefined"
So the scope is still limited with the keyword "new" ?

Comment: `new` has nothing to do with the scope of a variable. It allocates memory on the heap, that's all.

Comment: thx all for the precision. So if I rephrase my question : is there a way to access a variable outside its range of declaration ?

Comment: @Arcyno: That's a different question altogether. You can access any object within its lifetime, by name if it's a variable in scope, or via a reference or pointer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're confusing two separate concepts: the *scope* of a name, and the *lifetime* of an object. You're also confusing two separate objects: the pointer variable `s`, and the object of type `std::string` it points to.

`new std::string` creates an object with *dynamic lifetime*, which lasts until you delete it. It can be accessed from anywhere, as long as you have a pointer or reference to it. It doesn't have a name, so there's no scope involved.

`std::string * s` declares a variable with *block scope* and *automatic lifetime*. The name is accessible only within that scope, and the variable (the pointer, not any object it might point to) is destroyed when the program leaves that scope.

Answer (score 1):

The scope of s is limited by the surrounding {}. The string still exists in memory but you have lost the pointer to it. A memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

A variable/pointer's lexical scope and its memory scope are two different things. Here, s can not be referenced outside of its declaration block. However, the memory it occupies, until you delete it can be addressed.

Answer (score 0):

Some confusion here: `new std::string("foo");` *allocates* some memory and helpfully returns the address of that allocation.

Writing `std::string * s = ...` allows you to store that address, so you can `delete` the memory later.

But once you get past the closing brace, you no longer have that address stored since `s` will go out of scope. But the memory will remain allocated.

What you'll end up with is a memory leak, since you will have no way of `delete`ing the memory you allocated.

Answer (score 0):

Mike already answered the question, but in order to access your memory later you can do this (continuing your contrived example)

```
std::string *s;
{
    s = new std::string("Hello, World");
}
std::cout << *s << std::endl;
```

The good thing about pointers is that the pointer declaration doesn't call the default constructor of `std::string`, and when you use `new`, it calls the constructor of `std::string` and gives you a pointer back to the memory in the heap where it was constructed.